# Simplest way to add table headers background color in Latex

Tags: tables, header-footer, color, backgrounds

I am using this below code to generate a table,

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}
    \hline
    Title1 &  Title2 \\ \hline
    Item1 &  Item2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The output is like,

[image]

But I want to add background color for header row, like gray like,

[image]

What is the simplest way to add header background color for a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For coloring table rows you need to load `xcolor` package with option `table` (which use `colortbl` package) and than use command `\rowcolor{<color>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
    Title1 &  Title2 \\ \hline
    Item1 &  Item2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
    Title1 &  Title2 \\ 
    Item1 &  Item2 \\ 
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You will have a perfect output in all the PDF viewers, at all the levels of zoom because, in fact, in `nicematrix`, the rules are drawn by PGF/Tikz.

[image: Output of the above code]